# Django - How can I restrict a url access basing on the environment where the app is running

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I have the local and staging environment which I set using DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE. I want this URL to only be accessible in the staging environment. How can I know that the current environment is staging and restrict the URL to it.
Here is my url

```
path("testing_page/", views.testing_page_view, name="testing_page"),
```

The staging base url is `https://myapp-staging.domain.com/`

The view is

```
def testing_page_view(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, "testing_page.html")
    else:
        values = request.POST.dict()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(login_link)
```

Answer (score 1):

Access restrictions should be handled in your view. For example, you can raise a 404 exception if someone tries to access the path in the staging environment.

```
from djnago.conf import settings
from django.http import Http404

def testing_page_view(request):
    if settings.YOUR_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE == 'staging':
        #Here you can handle the case when the path is accessed in staging
        raise Http404('Only accessible in local environment')
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, "testing_page.html")
    else:
        values = request.POST.dict()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(login_link)
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to import the Django conf :

```
from django.conf import settings
```

Then depending on your case something like that could work :

```
"https://myapp-staging.domain.com/" if settings.DEBUG else "https://myapp.domain.com/"
```

This suppose that you have a debug that is different in staging and local, otherwise just add a new variable called **STAGING = TRUE**